# Differences between append and where in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df named `bas`. For example it looks like this:

```
    nat rac numberOnly  
0   DD  AR  548484554
1   AD  AR  168484245
2   FF  COL 484984554
3   WW  DE  484845225
...
```

It has 50k+ rows. I tried to got only records with `rac == AR or COL`.

I wrote that code:

```
AR = bas.where(bas.rac == "AR").dropna()
COL = bas.where(bas.rac == "COL").dropna()

DF = pd.DataFrame()
DF = DF.append(AR)
DF = DF.append(COL)
```

And Len of df is 27429. But the code dosen't look good. Especially that I want to filter more `rac` later. So I decided to recode it in this way:

```
DF = bas.where(bas.rac == ("AR" or "COL")).dropna()
```

And in this case DF has 27196 rows.

Why? What's the difference here? Which method is better? Maybe I should use something else, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your doing will definitely not work. You're looking for [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df[df.rac.isin(['AR', 'COL'])]

   nat  rac  numberOnly
0  DD   AR   548484554
1  AD   AR   168484245
2  FF  COL   484984554
```

Comment: Well @Artur , I'd suggest you have a look at the dupe, which contains some answers with nice explanations. Also read on what logical operators are used for, then you might see why `bas.rac == ("AR" or "COL")` is not doing at all what you think

Comment: Ok @yatu, thank U very much for answer and explanation. I know that or is something diffrent than `|` etc. but I think Ur right and I really need to go deeper in this subject. Thanks again :)